# Ruby Array of Hashes - For each financial year

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, hash

I have a transactions array, which contains transaction hashes. I’m wanting to loop through the array of transaction hashes, and for each financial year, sum the interest, and principal values. These then need to be added to the respective arrays, grouped by financial year, as shown below.

In short:

For each financial year:

1.Sum the values of the interest keys

2.Create a hash

3.Add the hash to the respective array

4.Repeat for the principal values

I'm a little stuck on the very first step: For each financial year, do x - Any help would be appreciated.

Ruby 2.3.1

Given

```
 @transactions = [
  {"interest" => "120.00", "principal" => "250", "financial_year" => "2017"},
  {"interest" => "120.00", "principal" => "250", "financial_year" => "2017"},
  {"interest" => "120.00", "principal" => "250", "financial_year" => "2017"},
  {"interest" => "120.00", "principal" => "250", "financial_year" => "2018"},
  {"interest" => "120.00", "principal" => "250", "financial_year" => "2018"},
  {"interest" => "120.00", "principal" => "250", "financial_year" => "2019"},
  {"interest" => "120.00", "principal" => "250", "financial_year" => "2019"}
 ]
```

I wish to compute

```
 @interest_totals = [
    {"financial_year" => "2017", "total" => "360"}
    {"financial_year" => "2018", "total" => "240"}
    {"financial_year" => "2019", "total" => "240"}
 ]
```

and

```
 @principal_totals = [
    {"financial_year" => "2017", "total" => "750"}
    {"financial_year" => "2018", "total" => "500"}
    {"financial_year" => "2019", "total" => "500"}
 ]
```

Comment: Although your typographic quotes look pretty, you have to use `"..."` and `'...'` instead of `“...”` and `‘...’` in Ruby.

Comment: I edited the question to correct the errors identified by @Stefan. James, please alway run you code (in IRB, say) to make sure it is correct before posting.

Comment: Will do @CarySwoveland - thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `inject` or `reduce` or `each_with_object`.  I used `each_with_object` below so that I can calculate the sum for both in one iteration

```
interests, principals = @transactions.each_with_object([Hash.new(0), Hash.new(0)]) do |transaction, (interests, principals)|
  interests[transaction['financial_year']] += transaction['interest'].to_d
  principals[transaction['financial_year']] += transaction['principal'].to_d
end

p interests
# {"2017"=>#<BigDecimal:7fd1c6cc20f0,'0.36E3',9(18)>, "2018"=>#<BigDecimal:7fd1c6cc1d30,'0.24E3',9(18)>, "2019"=>#<BigDecimal:7fd1c6cc1970,'0.24E3',9(18)>}

p principals
# {"2017"=>#<BigDecimal:7fd1c6cc2050,'0.75E3',9(18)>, "2018"=>#<BigDecimal:7fd1c6cc1c90,'0.5E3',9(18)>, "2019"=>#<BigDecimal:7fd1c6cc18d0,'0.5E3',9(18)>}
```

This will give you a hash where the year is the key and the value is the total.  If you really need an array of hashes, use `zip`

```
@interest_sum = interests.map do |interest|
  Hash[['financial_year', 'total'].zip(interest)]
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can group the values by year and then sum the principle and interest amount

```
@interest_totals =  @transactions.group_by{|a| a["financial_year"]}.map{|k, v| {"financial_year" => k, "total" => v.map{|e|e["interest"].to_i}.sum}}

#=> [{ "financial_year" => "2017", "total" => 360 },
#=>  { "financial_year" => "2018", "total" => 240 },
#=>  { "financial_year" => "2019", "total" => 240 }]

@principal_totals = @transactions.group_by{|a| a["financial_year"]}.map{|k, v| {"financial_year" => k, "total" => v.map{|e|e["principal"].to_i}.sum}}

#=> [{ "financial_year" => "2017", "total" => 750 },
#=>  { "financial_year" => "2018", "total" => 500 },
#=>  { "financial_year" => "2019", "total" => 500 }]
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you first compute the following hash.

```
h = @transactions.each_with_object({}) do |g,h|
  h.update(g["financial_year"]=>g.reject { |k,_| k=="financial_year" }) do |_,o,n|
    o.merge(n) { |_,oo,nn| (oo.to_i + nn.to_i).to_s }
  end
end
  #=> {"2017"=>{"interest"=>"360", "principal"=>"750"},
  #    "2018"=>{"interest"=>"240", "principal"=>"500"},
  #    "2019"=>{"interest"=>"240", "principal"=>"500"}}
```

This uses the form of [Hash#update](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Hash.html#method-i-update) (aka `merge!`) and [Hash#merge](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Hash.html#method-i-merge) that employ a block to determine the values of keys that are present in both hashes being merged. See the docs for details, especially the values of the block variables, `_`, `o`, `n`, `k`, `oo` and `nn`. (In the first block I've used an underscore for the common key to signify that it is not used in the block calculation.)

One advantage of this intermediate solution is that it needn't be changed if keys (other than "financial_year") are added ("balance", say), deleted or renamed.

You can now easily construct other objects. For example,

```
@interest_totals = h.map { |year,v| {"financial_year"=>year, "total"=> v["interest"] } }
  #=> [{"financial_year"=>"2017", "total"=>"360"},
  #    {"financial_year"=>"2018", "total"=>"240"},
  #    {"financial_year"=>"2019", "total"=>"240"}]
```